# processing underlined/bold/italics text in android

Tags: java, android

I am using jxl api to process contents from an excel file and load them into a json string. I then parse the json string and display contents in various TextViews in my screen. If the excel has any underlined/bold/italics text, then it is not being displayed accordingly in the TextView. Can someone suggest how to make sure any text with underline/bold/italics done in excel gets displayed in textview as well.
Below is the code I am using to process string from excel file

```
w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
Sheet sheet = w.getSheet(0);
Cell storyNameCell = sheet.getCell(1,1);
String Title = storyNameCell.getContents();
//get more cells into Strings
//form the json string from all the String contents above
```

And this is how I am saving the JSON string above into a local file on android device

```
    String FILENAME = getString(R.string.app_name)+"_"+storyTitle;
      FileOutputStream output = openFileOutput(FILENAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output, "UTF-8");
        writer.write(jObjStoryTitle.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
```

And finally I am getting any JSON string out of the file for display purpose on user request.

```
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getBaseContext().openFileInput( quizFileName), "UTF-8"));
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null)
            fileContent.append(str);
        fileString = new String(fileContent);
        jObjStoryTitle = new JSONObject(fileString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get around it. Here is what I did.
-used apache POI api for reading xls file in my android app. Jxl api was not helpful as that does not have capability to recognize any font/style embedded within the part of the text in a cell.
-So using the Apache-POI I then could figure out which part of the text contains underlined characters.
-I then embedded html tags before/after that part
- Then used the Html object to display in Textview as below

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(underlinedText));
```